# I want to use `set` in data.table to become all -1 to NA

Tags: r, data.table

how can i use `set` function in data.table like
 `apply(data,2,function(x){ifelse(x==-1,NA,x)})`? I want to all -1 in my data become NA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this with by first convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(data)`), loop through the columns of 'data', and `set` the `value` to NA where logical condition (`shich(data[[j]]== -1)`) matches for the row elements

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)
for(j in seq_along(data)) {
   set(data, i = which(data[[j]]== -1), j = j, value = NA)
 }

 data
#    V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
#1:  0 NA  3 NA NA
#2:  0  0  0 NA  4
#3:  3  3  3 NA  3
#4:  4 NA  3  4 NA
#5:  3  0  0 NA  0
```

---

This can also done in a compact way with `base R`

```
NA^(data== -1)*data
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
data <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c(-1, 0, 4, 3, NA), 25, replace=TRUE), 5, 5))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! BTW,if i wantn't to use `for` loop in data.table, how can i do ?

Comment: You can use `lapply` i.e. `setDT(data)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) replace(x, x==-1, NA))]`, but the assignment method with `set` might be faster